# Difference between Debugging Configurations in CDT Eclipse?

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse CDT have different debugging configurations like

- C/C++ Application
- C/C++ Attach to Application
- C/C++ Container Launcher
- C/C++ Postmortem Debugger
- C/C++ Remote Application
- GDB Hardware Debugging

What exactly is the difference between theses Configurations? Any source where I can study will do just fine.